# Check GPS status with COARSE permission

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I'm able to check if user has enabled GPS location via calback

```
LocationManagerCompat.registerGnssStatusCallback.
```

Problem is that it needs ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission but I'd like to use is also when user enables only ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. Is there any clean solution how to achieve it.

Right now, I repeatedly check locationSettings which is not optimal.

```
locationStatusTimer = Timer().schedule(0, LOCATION_STATUS_REQUEST_PERIOD) {
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity)
                    .checkLocationSettings(
                        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                            .build()
                    ).addOnSuccessListener {
                        deviceLocationController.updateLocationStatus(DeviceLocationStatus.Enabled)
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        deviceLocationController.updateLocationStatus(DeviceLocationStatus.Disabled)
                    }
            }
```

Comment: FINE==gps.......

Comment: Right. I thought location that you can turn on/off via toggle.